# Mongo document count different from console.logged count

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Doing some experimenting to get a grasp of the basics on my road to learning how to code. Been messing around with one aspect all day but can't figure it out. I'm sure it must be something simple and would appreciate any help!

So I've created a Mongo collection:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
```

I then added 3 documents into the collection, with 2 fields each (name and quantity). Now, when in the Google Chrome console I run:

```
Posts.find().count();

//returns '3' as expected
```

However, when instead I run the following code from the server (is it called the server if it is the client side code?):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var c = Posts.find().count();
  console.log("The database documents count is " + c);
}
```

Then it comes up on Chrome console as:

```
The database documents count is 0
```

What gives? What's going on here?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: seems like subscription to `Posts` is not ready yet so you have `0` by calling `count()` function

Comment: I haven't yet removed autopublish/insecure so the console has access to the entire database (confirmed by being able to read and manipulate the documents from the console). :S

Comment: Even if you have autopublish, it takes some time to deliver (publish) data from the server to the client. When your JS code runs, publish is not completed yet.

Comment: But then why does the count function within the browser console return the correct number? Wouldn't that point to the published data having been completed (and the fact that the published data is displaying on the page)? :S

Comment: You should mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it works: when you open a page, the client has no data at all. After your JS is loaded, publish functions begin to work and after some time, when publishing is over, you have data on the client.

So at the moment when browser runs:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  console.log(Posts.find().count());
}
```

You have no data on the client, that's why you see `0` in the console.

But then you open console manually and write `Posts.find().count()`. It took some time for you to open the console, to write `Posts.find().count()` and this time was enough for publish functions to send all data to the client, so now you have data on the client and you will see `3` in the console.

You can try this experiment:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(Posts.find().count());
  }, 2000);
}
```

It will log posts count not immediately, but with 2 seconds delay, this should be enough for publishing to be over and you will see `3` in the console. You can change timeout delay and find out how much does it take for the server to send posts data to the client.

Comment: Imkost you legend!!! Thank you so much, for the solution and for explaining a fundamental that I'm sure will translate to a lot of other areas. (My apologies for the late response)